"java.io.IOException: Cannot allocate memory" in Java when writing to array with FileInputStream
We're running into a situation where we are unable to read bytes from a file into an array initialized on the heap, below is the (simplified) source code:
FileInputStream inp = ...;
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
inp.read(buf, 0, buf.length);  <<< this is where OOM is reached

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot allocate memory
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:276)

We run this Java process in a containerized application in Docker/AWS ECS. We create a small (1kB) on-heap array buffer as a temporary location to stream the file in; we then copy this buffer into "native memory" (we use the Unsafe API for latency considerations, but this is not where the OOM occurs anyways).
This error occurs when we are already pretty close to our container memory limit. However, I'd expect the OOM to be triggered upon array initialization (when creating buf) as here Java will initialize the array to all 0s, thereby committing the pages to physical memory and hitting any OOM errors there (the most common case I see on Stack Overflow, see this post or this post).
But instead we see it while copying data into the already initialized array, where there shouldn't be any additional memory allocations. Since it occurs at readBytes (a native method that likely just calls an underlying OS memcpy), I'd think its during the array copy and not while creating some heap objects in the middle.
Is there any explanation for why see the OOM error during the memory copy and not during initilization?

This is not a OOM exception creating your buffer, it’s a IOException reading your file. There is a native memory allocation of a 2k array inside read()’s native part. That’s what the message is referring to. And read() isn’t ’an underlying OS memcpy()’.  You must be seriously close to the limit. Fix that.

That would explain it. Yeah we're investigating/fixing a OOM scenario we hit, trying to root-cause why we get OOM on this line in particular. Are you referring to any low-level source code for the native method, or any docs?

The C source code for InputStream.read0() or whatever it calls. It’s been decades since I saw it.

@nocomment I see no cogent reason for your edit.

@user207421 See the tag's description. Feel free to add the correct tag instead.
